# Mongoid embedding one class as multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to track a user's current, previous and chosen (changes at end of period) subscription states.

At the end of the monthly period, if `chosen_subscription != current_subscription`, the `current_subscription` gets changed.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :previous_subscription, class_name: "Subscription"
  embeds_one :current_subscription, class_name: "Subscription"
  embeds_one :chosen_subscription, class_name: "Subscription"
end

class Subscription
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user

  field :plan, type: String
  field :credits, type: Integer
  field :price_per_credit, type: BigDecimal

  field :start, type: Date
  field :end, type: Date
end
```

Mongoid wants me to specify this more and in a way that does not make sense to me:

```
Mongoid::Errors::AmbiguousRelationship:

Problem:
  Ambiguous relations :previous_subscription, :current_subscription, :chosen_subscription defined on User.
Summary:
  When Mongoid attempts to set an inverse document of a relation in memory, it needs to know which relation it belongs to. When setting :user, Mongoid looked on the class Subscription for a matching relation, but multiples were found that could potentially match: :previous_subscription, :current_subscription, :chosen_subscription.
Resolution:
  On the :user relation on Subscription you must add an :inverse_of option to specify the exact relationship on User that is the opposite of :user.
```

This happens when I overwrite an existing current_subscription. I suppose, at this moment, Mongoid wants to unregister the old subscription's user's subscription.

Of course, every subscription object only belongs to one user and the `user == user.previous_subscription.user == user.current_subscription.user == user.chosen_subscription.user`

Yet it does not make sense to me to tell `Subscription` that `user` is inverse of any one of the three.

How should I build it right?

Comment: I am not quite sure how would you build it right, but you can try asking on monogid google group. The problem mongoid is telling you about is that if you do `subscription.user = some_user` it doesn't know which subscription are you are you talking about from user perspective. You can also try setting `inverse_of: nil` if you are not going to use `subscription.user=` in your code.

Comment: I never set subscription.user directly. I think it got set implicitly when I set user.*_subscription. inverse_of: nil worked well for me. If you would create an answer for it, I will mark it correct.

Comment: I have expanded the comment into the answer with a little more information and some gotchas with the suggestion. I do not believe it is the ideal solution, but works for me in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says: you must add an :inverse_of option. Try this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :previous_subscription, class_name: "Subscription", inverse_of: :previous_subscription
  embeds_one :current_subscription, class_name: "Subscription", inverse_of: :current_subscription
  embeds_one :chosen_subscription, class_name: "Subscription", inverse_of: :chosen_subscription
end

class Subscription
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user, inverse_of: :previous_subscription
  embedded_in :user, inverse_of: :current_subscription
  embedded_in :user, inverse_of: :chosen_subscription

  field :plan, type: String
  field :credits, type: Integer
  field :price_per_credit, type: BigDecimal

  field :start, type: Date
  field :end, type: Date
end
```

Comment: I would have thought embedding_in could not be used multiple times, especially for the same parent. But this works. For the embeds_one, I used inverse_of: :user however.

Answer (score 0):

Every mongoid relation has an inverse relation which is used to setup both the sides correctly. Most of the times it can be identified correctly based on naming conventions, classes used etc., but sometimes you need to define them explicitly.

The problem mongoid is complaining about here is that the relations defined in `User` model are ambiguous, as mongoid can't identify which of them maps to `subscription.user` relation in `Subscription`. More over, when `subscription.user = some_user` is used, mongoid can't identify if you need to set `previous_subscription`, `current_subscription` or `chosen_subscription` in user to the subscription object. Even if you do not explicitly call this method, you can face these issues as mongoid tries to set the inverse when you set a relation.

I am not sure if this is the right way to build the system, but you can define `inverse_of: nil` in your relations to tell mongoid to not set inverse relations when setting a relation. This approach should only be used if you never need to use `subscription.user=` in your code. `subscription.user` can also have issues, but one can use undocumented methods `doc._parent` or `doc._root` if you absolutely need them. This approach although solves the issue but has its own demerits. I have attempted to show them here with following code:

```
class Tester
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_one :first_module, class_name: 'TestModule', inverse_of: nil
  embeds_one :last_module, class_name: 'TestModule', inverse_of: nil

end

class TestModule
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  # not needed as such, but required to tell mongoid that this is a embedded document
  embedded_in :tester, inverse_of: nil
end

t1 = Tester.new(name: 't1')
m1 = t1.build_first_module(name: 't1m1')
m2 = t1.build_last_module(name: 't1m2')

t1.first_module == m1 #=> true
t1.last_module == m2  #=> true

m1.tester             #=> nil
m2.tester             #=> nil 

t1.save
t1 = Tester.last
m1 = t1.first_module
m2 = t1.last_module

t1.first_module == m1 #=> true
t1.last_module == m2  #=> true

m1.tester             #=> nil
m2.tester             #=> nil
```

There have been a few discussions about something like this on mongoid issue tracker too: [#1677](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/1677) & [#3086](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3086)